# I need a SQL query for top 5 upcoming birthdays and recent previous birthdays

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query to the today birthdays user.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_EmployeeInfo WHERE MONTH(DOB) = MONTH(getdate()) and day(DOB)=day(getdate())
```

But I need top 5 users SQL query for upcoming birthdays, not today users birthday, it should be tomorrow, if no body will tomorrow means take from next days.

Also, I need recent top 5 user birthdays gone, not today users birthday.

Comment: Table Name:Table_EmployeeInfo  and Table Fields: Name, DOB,EmailID, SubmisionDate etc.. Why Table Structure require?. @sagi

Comment: Do you want two separate query?

Comment: Yes I want seperate query. @UbiquitousDevelopers

Comment: DOB contains year also, If I am not  wrong?

Comment: what if you are in new year ?

Comment: yes.. DOB value inserted like this:  1959-08-05 00:00:00.000.. @UbiquitousDevelopers

Comment: then no need to convert it into day

Comment: Can you update your answer. @NeerajPrasadSharma

Comment: you want 2 different ResultSet or both combined

Comment: I want seperate query. @NeerajPrasadSharma

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT t.*,
    row_number() OVER(order by datepart(mm,t.DOB),datepart(dd,t.DOB)) as rnk
    FROM Table_EmployeeInfo t
    where t.DOB > getdate())
WHERE rnk <= 5
```

Comment: I need both query for upcoming and recent. @sagi

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.  getting error. @sagi

Answer (score 0):

Messy, but it works:

```
select * from (
SELECT datediff(dd,DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yyyy, DOB, GETDATE()), DOB),getdate()) as daysSinceBD
,  DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY datediff(dd,DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yyyy, DOB, GETDATE()), DOB),getdate()) desc ) as Ranking
,  * FROM Table_EmployeeInfo 
 where datediff(dd,DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yyyy, DOB, GETDATE()), DOB),getdate()) < 0 

 )x   where ranking <=5 order by 1 desc
```

Comment: I need both query seperately. @SeanR

Answer (score 0):

Try this below for select upcoming 5 birthdays

```
SELECT top 5 * FROM Table_EmployeeInfo WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DOB, 111)) > CONVERT(DATETIME,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)) order by dob
```

This one for past 5 birthdays

```
SELECT top 5 * FROM Table_EmployeeInfo WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DOB, 111)) < CONVERT(DATETIME,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)) order by dob
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the codes against an old database with Date of Birth data, and they worked. 
Since I do not have Date of Birth exact time (hour and etc), I did not handle the situation where I have 10 or more people with birthday on same day.

I have used the "OFFSET - FETCH" approach, that can help you if you need some kind of pagination in the future.

I do not know your scenario and/or data model, but if this query is to be run frequently and database tends to be big, I'd suggest you to consider a computed column "Anniversary", or anything compliant with your database names convention. This is because you have to use a lot of functions to achieve what you need, and this is not good for performance. With a computed column, you have less complexity on queries and a better indexing strategy.

Please find below the code I have written, and let me know if it helps.

```
-- LAST 5 BIRTHDAYS GONE, NOT FROM TODAY
SELECT 
*
FROM 
    Table_EmployeeInfo AS T
WHERE 
    DATEPART(DD, T.DOB) < DATEPART(DD, GETDATE())
AND 
    DATEPART(MM, T.DOB) <= DATEPART(MM, GETDATE())
ORDER BY
     DATEPART(MM, T.DOB) DESC
    ,DATEPART(DD, T.DOB) DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY

-- NEXT 5 BIRTHDAYS TO COME, NOT FROM TODAY
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
    Table_EmployeeInfo AS T
WHERE 
    DATEPART(DD, T.DOB) > DATEPART(DD, GETDATE())
    AND 
    DATEPART(MM, T.DOB) >= DATEPART(MM, GETDATE())
ORDER BY
     DATEPART(MM, T.DOB) ASC
    ,DATEPART(DD, T.DOB) ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

P.S.: OFFSET-FETCH will work only on SQL Server 2012 or above. If you are using and older version, try using TOP(5) instead.